# Powershell with HTML Formatting

Tags: html, powershell

So I am creating a basic HTML report for a System Server Audit, some extracts which are relevant:

```
$system = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $cmpSys Win32_ComputerSystem 

$body = $null
$body += @"
<font color="red">Hostname: </font>$cmpSys
<br>
<font color="red">Domain: </font>($system.Domain)
<br>
"@
```

Now, `Hostname: $cmpSys` - correctly produces `Hostname in red` and the `hostname in black`

However, I am calling $system.Domain in the format later on, which produces in my report:

```
Domain: (\\W7WKS01\root\cimv2:Win32_ComputerSystem.Name="W7WKS01".Domain)
```

But it should just display W7WKS01

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `$($system.Domain)`, not just `($system.Domain)`. Without the leading `$` the parentheses are just literal parentheses inside a string, and `$system.Domain` is expanded to the default attribute of `$system` (`__PATH`) followed by a literal ".Domain".